# CSS Background full fitting on android

Tags: android, css, background

I am working on a project where i must make an image as a full fitting background whatever the device - browser - windows size are , after hours and hours of researchs on the net this is the best CSS setting i got :

```
background: url(datas/bg.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
```

that, works fine in all browsers & devices and the image fits the background perfectly.
However , on Android system the image is not fitting vertically , it's shifted to the top as u can see

[Here](http://ajnadeen-me.com/eBook/bugs/index.html) .

I've tried as well this

```
background: url(datas/bg.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: 100%; 
-moz-background-size: 100%; 
-o-background-size: 100%; 
background-size: 100%; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover;
```

but still not working

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played too much with the CSS processing on android devices there is a tag for CSS that is `background-position`.  As far as I can see you haven't used this in your code above.  Here is a link to the W3 schools info about the background tag.

[CSS background property on W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Comment: Actually this line: background: url(datas/bg.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed; contains the position that are center - center , means 50% on the X (center) and 50% on the Y (center) But thanks for you help .